# How to monitor the visual processor of Pixel 2 usage

Tags: android, neural-network

I am wondering how I can monitor the usage of Google's visual core.

I am playing with the recent Android Neural Networks (ANNs) API using Pixel 2 on Android 8.1 operating system. 
I tried the sample NDK program and TensorFlow lite Android demo (the links to are provided below):
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/nn_sample
https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/demo_android

Both programs are working fine. But I have not idea if the visual core is actually utilized. The ANNs API distributes the computation to the available cores automatically. 
Is there any API that I can use to find out the utilization of the visual core?

Thanks,
Yitao

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Tensorflow Lite does not provide API to monitor resource utilization. I am not sure if there are any system monitors for visual core in Pixel phone.